# Reduce the space between labels and label alignment

Tags: html, asp.net

[image]

my source is like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Department Code"></asp:Label>
                              </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtDepCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Department Name"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <asp:TextBox ID="textDepName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
```

i want to make my two labels in same alignment and reduce space between ..how i can do in this?

any help is very appriciable

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the space between two labels use '&nbsp' in text property of label

Comment: in the text property of the label

Comment: sir i am very new to this program.if you can can you write that line of code?

Comment: <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="&nbsp&nbspDepartment Code">

Answer (score 0):

Try putting some css in there or '&nbsp' in text property of label(s).

Comment: @user3262364 what I mean by 'text property' is after the 'text ='; anything after the equals in quotations is the 'property' of 'text'  so if you want to space instead of: 'Text="department Name">' you would do: 'Text=&nbsp&nbspDepartment Name">'   &nbsp means 'non-breaking space' aka no space.